# URL Rewrite rewrite x.php?id=1

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I've searched the site and got far enough where I've been successful at rewriting to a clean URL. Just need a bit more help.

I have a page with a record that I have successfully rewritten to a clean URL like so:

`domain/record.php?id=1685 > to > domain/record-Gavin-Rees-1685` using the below:

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^record-(.*)-(.*)$ /record.php?id=$2 [L]
```

This in my php file:

```
$temp=str_replace(' ','-', $record [record_name]);
$temp=str_replace('.','', $temp);

<a href='/record-". $temp ."-".$record[id]." '>
```

This works perfect. The problem is.

I cannot get it to rewrite the other way so if you go directly to:

```
/record.php?id=1685 it still exists. i tried > RewriteRule ^record.php?id=$ /record-(.*)-(.*)$ [R,L]
```

Comment: You can't add information that you don't have. mod_rewrite has no way to know that for ID 1685 those blanks should be filled with "Gavin" and "Rees". In your first case, you're only using information that's in the original request URL, which is why it works.

Comment: Correct, that’s why you should handle that in your script. Find out how the script was originally requested (look into $_SERVER) – and then if it was called the “wrong” way, look up the necessary data in your database and redirect the client to the desired URL with a Location header.

Comment: sorry im not following.

Comment: if record.php is in the root of your domain, you do not need to make a rewrite.

Comment: yes record.php is in root. so i do this in the script? ok let me research and i see someone gave a suggest below.

Comment: You should really think of `Routing` instead of rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in the .htacces rewrite rules, because you couldn't define a general rule, which knows about your software internals. If you want to do this in your .htaccess file, you have to create a rule for every single id which would result in a very large and unhandy .htaccess file.

The better way to get an redirection for direct script calls is, to do the redirect in the php file itself and set the http status codes(i.e. 301 - permanently moved).
The get the requested url, you could use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and check for `/record.php` at the beginning